# Changing the WebService method result name

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

This is probably an easy thing, but I haven't found a working way of doing it.

I have a C# web service which currently has an output like this:

```
<GetInformationResponse>
  <GetInformationResult>
    <Policy>
    </Policy>
  </GetInformationResult>
<GetInformationResponse>
```

What I need is output like this:

```
<GetInformationResponse>
  <InformationResponse>
    <Policy>
    </Policy>
  </InformationResponse>
<GetInformationResponse>
```

I've tried wrapping everything in an "InformationResponse" object, but I still have the "GetInformationResult" object encapsulating it.  I basically need to rename "GetInformationResult" to "InformationResponse".

Thanks!

ETA: Object/method information

```
[WebMethod]
public InformationResponse GetInformation(GetInformationRequest GetInformationRequest)
{
  InformationResponse infoSummary = new InformationResponse();
  Policy policy = new Policy();
  // setting values

  return infoSummary;
}
```

InformationResponse object:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(typeof(Policy))]
public class InformationResponse : List<Policy>
{
  private Policy policyField;

  /// <remarks/>
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Policy", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
  public Policy Policy
  {
    get
    {
        return this.policyField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.policyField = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to specify more details. Is it a SOAP service? Why do you care about those internals? ...?

Comment: Is the Web Service generated through a WSDL or from code? Can we see whichever one defines this message?

Comment: It's a SOAP service, generated through code.  Personally, I don't care about the internals but management has set the schema in stone and it has to match the above.

Comment: Is this an ASMX or WCF service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, using an `XmlElementAttribute` will allow you to redefine the name of a serialized element. However, in an ASMX web service, this doesn't seem to work. However, by using an attribute on the WebMethod I was able to produce the behavior you're looking for. Try this:

```
[WebMethod]
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("InformationResponse")]
public InformationResponse GetInformation(GetInformationRequest GetInformationRequest)
{  
   ....
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but the result was this: `<GetInformationResponse> <InformationResponse> </InformationResponse><InformationResponse> </InformationResponse></GetInformationResponse>`
If I encapsulate it, it turns out like this: `<GetInformationResponse> <InformationResponse><InformationResponse> </InformationResponse></InformationResponse></GetInformationResponse>`

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to add the XmlRoot declaration like this:

```
[XmlRoot("MyName")]
public class MyName
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved similar problem I modified WSDL and remove result element, then generate proxy class with wsdl.exe and use proxy class for my ASMX